# fastboot does not discover my device

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, fastboot

I want to connect my device (Omega T107) in fastboot mode.

1. I reboot in bootloader mode (adb reboot bootloader)
2. Screen is black(0 light comming out of it) computer can discover it and driver installs properly
3. fastboot devices returns empty list

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does `adb get-serialno` show you the correct device number?

Comment: What platform are you accessing the phone from? (Windows, Linux, ...)

Answer (score 1):

`fastboot` is just one of the protocols to talk to the bootloader. Some manufacturers choose to support it (e.g. Google, HTC), others choose to make their bootloaders talk some other protocol (e.g. Samsung).

After googling a little bit, I don’t think that the bootloader of your device supports `fastboot` (at least, there are no mentions of this). Most likely, you will need a special tool from your manufacturer that will be able to talk to your device in bootloader mode.

Answer (score 0):

The command 'fastboot devices' shows only the devices it can access properly with fastboot protocol.

- Check if you have sufficient rights for accessing the device (either do it with root or [add aproppriate UDEV rules](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)).
- Check if you really started the device into fastboot mode

Comment: How do I make sure I've started in fastboot mode when bootloader is a black screen ?

Comment: Look at this answer that explains how to [create the udev rule](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/fastboot-not-working-on-my-nexus-4/37085#37085).