# SGN 4.2.1 - stuck at < waiting for device >

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, adb, 4.2-jelly-bean, recovery-mode

I own Samsung Galaxy Nexus, it has been unlocked, rooted, I'm using CWM Recovery Touch and a few weeks ago I updated firmware to `4.2.1` (build `JOP40D`). It seems that `Superuser` is no longer working on `4.2` versions and I must use `SuperSu` (so I installed it from the Play, but probably it's not at all). Problems:

- can't start Recovery in fastboot mode, it shows something like `no command` on some error screen (but in my language). Before this screen it tries to boot or something (Google logo for a while).
- can't do anything with ADB or Galaxy Nexus Toolkit, after reboot to the fastboot I stuck at `<waiting for device>` message.
- can't update CWM Recovery from CWM Rom Manager, probably due to `su` problem.

I haven't found any solution within discussions (useless as always), but everybody's asking about `adb devices`, so my output is: `0149A5310A021040        device`

I can hack it with my Windows or Linux, but need some advice, thanks.

Comment: Seen [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/fastboot-not-working-on-my-nexus-4/37085#37085)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, but I don't understand what happened. While I got stuck on `<waiting for device>` message, I've tried `Reboot bootloader` option and process has been successfully completed. But I haven't to do this first time when I was unlocking, rooting, and installing Recovery and AOKP.