# No Permissions Error Regardless of sudo or shell

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, huawei-u8150

I have a Huawei comet u8150 That I decided to root seeing as I'm stuck with it for the time being. I rooted it last night, Flashed Clockwork Mod Recovery 5.0.2 and Installed CyanogenMod 7 for the U8150. Now before I installed Cyanogen I was able to access the device via adb using sudo -s and starting the server via a root shell. Now I can run it as sudo or a root shell and I get the same issue. Inside of 51-android.rules I have

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666"
```

and my output of lsusb is

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 064e:a110 Suyin Corp. HP Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1038 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

You can see that 12d1 is included inside of the 51-android.rules file, so I'm not sure where to go from here as everyone tells me to drop to a root shell which has not worked as well. Thanks in advance.
---UPDATE---
Thought I'd give some extra input on the matter real fast.
If I perform an adb pull or an adb shell that seems to be working. However when I try to utilize adb push or nano while in the superuser adb shell I don't have permissions to modify. It recognizes my device, but that's it.
I'm sure I have the rules set correctly, but the problem is I can use

`sudo -s`

and operate from within the root shell and I have the same output when using adb devices. Hopefully someone will have some thoughts as to what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the ?????? isn't just to have a ? in the title. It's what the device is being read as.

Comment: I had a similar issue once, wrote a long post, and immediately before hitting the button I figured out I had forgotten to turn *USB Debugging* on in the device. Might sound stupid -- but it was me, so I can say so. Could it be a similar thing in your case?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Izzy. Unfortunately I do have USB debugging enabled. I wish it was that easy for me as well.

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear! Are you trying to access the device from your linux terminal, i.e. `adb shell` to drop into the android terminal and do whatever? Or is it the fact your computer is not recognizing your device?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/fastboot-not-working-on-my-nexus-4/37085#37085) to make sure you have your rules done correctly - FYI! This is not *just* for fastboot but is a general consensus in getting your machine to recognize your handset!

Comment: Sorry; Trying to access it directly from the Linux Terminal utilizing adb commands. It was working with the stock rom when I dropped to the Linux root shell, but after changing to CyanogenMod it seems like it's behaving as if I don't have the permissions. I'm not sure what else to do from here. My rules are correctly set. I've also changed up my rules a tad bit by the link t0mm13 put up.